# PostgreSQL link and unlink rows in chain manner

Tags: sql, postgresql, chain

A Document can be called family member if they share any common docid.

Simple Mapping looks like:

```
Docs: docid
1 : a,b
2 : a,c,d
3 : d,e,f
4 : b,g
```

in table this data looks like :

```
1 = a
1 = b
2 = a
2 = c
2 = d
3 = d
3 = e
3 = f
4 = b
4 = g
```

Here 1,2,3,4 Documents are family as they have commons like : 1 and 2 share "a" as common, 2 and 3 share "d" as common and 1 and 4 share "b" as common.

I can achieve this grouping by making a separate table of it and while inserting checking if any record exists then assigning existing value to all the docid.

```
When doc 1 is inserted :
checks any of (a,b) already in family table:
if no:
  insert into table and get a famid
```

hence inserts : a = 1 and b=1 rows.

and for other cases
eg doc 2 case

```
: any (a,c,d) exists --> doc 1 has been inserted hence output : a = 1

so take this value and assign to a,c,d (separate entries: a=1, c=1, d=1)and upsert into family table.
```

So the family table looks like:

```
Docs : docid : famid
1    :   a   :  1
1    :   b   :  1
2    :   c   :  1
2    :   d   :  1
3    :   e   :  1
3    :   f   :  1
4    :   g   :  1
```

**I want to keep this as to maintain group by so that in this case if I have doc 1,2,3,4 i can group by famid and return any one of these 4 docs.**

**My concern** is these docid may contain manual error hence after few days "a" might get unlink from doc1 so logically docs 2 and 3 should not be member of family famid 1 anymore but the family table still stores it hence complete chain gets corrupted is there a way I can store and maintain so as to unlink in case of deletion of a common node in chain.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string.  And especially don't call what you are storing "numbers" when they are clearly letters.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff, I have put some clarity to it, actually that was just mapping importantly multiple values are not stores in same string they have multiple entries for it. and numbers is docid now.